# WooCommerce api authentication error oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I try to fetch all product data list in json from WooCommerce API and type address bar http://www.batata.in/wc-api/v3/orders. But it give an error:

> {"errors"[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}

I tried all things but issue is not fixed. Rest API is on.

[image: this type of error are shown]

If anybody know any other way to find product list in json format from WooCommerce WordPress plugins, then please tell me.

Comment: May be you don't know, but if you are using WooCommerce 2.6+, there is a new Rest API merged from WordPress Rest API standard: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/ . I don't know if that can helps, I hope so.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. After some research, I have solved this issue. Kindly check that your site secure or not [http or https]. I missed the "s" for http.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you need to provide consumer key, nonce, signature with your rest api call. Following is the format which worked for me.

http://SomeURL.com/wc-api/v2/orders?oauth_consumer_key=########&oauth_timestamp=######&oauth_nonce=#############&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_signature=##########################

For generating nonce and signature I recommend you use some wrapper available for your platform. I used php so got a nice library here.

https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php

Important:- Even after following all above steps correct I got the same issue you faced. It kept giving me error "oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing" which actually was misleading. The issue I figured out was the basic http auth. I had http authentication in place so the curl request I used to fire was returning 401 unauthorized. If you are using php you will understand following line.

curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");

And it worked. So point here is you can try this or play around with your curl/socket or any client you are building and don't focus on the error message as it is misleading most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Sandipa Mukherjee's answer is right.

For http:// additional oauth parameters are required, because it's not safe.

My suggestion is to use the https:// server for wordpress.

Please refer to https://scriptstown.com/how-to-setup-cloudflare-ssl-and-configure-origin-certificate-for-apache/